# MS-Access: Selecting rows to delete via joins

Tags: ms-access

I found [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/439750/t-sql-selecting-rows-to-delete-via-joins) that is discussing what I would like to do, but it's for T-SQL. Is there a way to do something similar in Microsoft Access?  The examples below are based off what I found in that question.

I need to delete all the records in `TableA`, which is linked to `TableB` via field `Bid` based on another field in `TableB`.

Here is the query that selects the items to be deleted:

```
SELECT * 
FROM TableA a
INNER JOIN TableB b on b.Bid = a.Bid
WHERE [my filter condition]
```

The following query results in an error "Specify the table containing the records you want to delete."

```
DELETE TableA 
FROM TableA a
INNER JOIN TableB b on b.Bid = a.Bid
WHERE [my filter condition]
```

Is this possible with an Access query?

Comment: Answer available in below URL : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5585732/how-to-delete-in-ms-access-when-using-joins

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This should work:

```
DELETE TableB.Text, TableA.*
FROM TableA 
INNER JOIN TableB ON TableA.BID = TableB.BID
WHERE TableB.Text="foo";
```