# Access 2010 SQL - Show Duplicate Records in Order for eventual Deletion (pure SQL Solution pls)

Tags: sql, ms-access, duplicates, ms-access-2010, records

I have the following table named 'flt'

You can see the duplicates are identifed by 3 columns only `(flight, fltno, stad)`... I don't care about what is in `col1 and col2.`. But I should be able to show it in the query.

So.. you can see `ids 8, 3 and 10` are **duplicates**.

I want to write a pure SQL query... that can do the following:

1) the `duplicate count` column.. which basically counts how many records are there that matches the `flight, fltno, stad` of the currently selected row.

2) the `"duplicate rank"` column which orders the duplicates.. 1 means first record, 2 means this is the 2nd record and 3 means this is the 3rd record. You can see `ba 104` has 2 records in total... and it is ranked 1 and 2.

3) from the resulting (possibly editable) query.. I should be able to filter out (using where) all the duplicate ranks that are `> 1`... then able to delete those records. 
So.. `id 8, 3 and 10 are > 1`.. and I should be able to delete them with in this query... by clicking on the row and delete key.

If the condition 3 is not entirely achievable.. please give me the best way possible. Thanks.

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This SQL will get you the results as per your question, however it won't work as part of a DELETE query, I suggest SELECTING from this query into a temporary table and then running a DELETE query from that : )

```
SELECT A.id, A.flight, A.fltno, A.stad, A.col1, A.col2, B.concount AS [duplicate count], (SELECT Count(C.id) FROM tblfit As C WHERE C.flight&C.fltno&C.stad=A.concat AND C.id <= A.id) AS [duplicate rank]
FROM (SELECT tblfit.*, [flight] & [fltno] & [stad] AS concat
FROM tblfit) AS A,
(SELECT [flight] & [fltno] & [stad] AS concat, Count([concat]) AS concount
FROM tblfit
GROUP BY [flight] & [fltno] & [stad]) AS B
WHERE A.concat = B.concat;
```

Comment: i am re-adjusting your query to fit my actual table and think i can make it work.. However, I just want to highlight that there are some bracketing issues.. [ instead of (... and an extra '.'. Pls let me know. I will advise the final query when I could make it work here again. Thanks.

Comment: @ihightower The original query is written using standard brackets without .'s before the alias, however when using joins against derived tables, Access automatically amends the SQL to include the [ and .'s, not sure why to be honest

Comment: @ihightower I've amended the query to use joins in the WHERE clause instead to avoid the bracketing issues, please see updated SQL : )

Comment: that was the exact change i made... and it now works great. Thank you so much. Got what I wanted... For wanting more.. Just wondering if this is the normal efficient approach... (as the response time is little slow)... and anyway to make the recordset editable.

Comment: @ihightower Ranking queries are sadly not native to Access like other databases and so the repeated running of the count SQL will slow things down, checking you have all the necessary table indexes may help. There is no way to make this sort of query directly editable, however the link provided by a shareef may allow you to incorporate this query into a DELETE query. As a side note, try a compact and repair after saving this query as Access will then re-evaluate its query execution plans and may speed things up.

Answer (score 0):

Added a column in the table where the value is always 1 called

```
countValue
```

Then the first query for duplicate count is

```
SELECT tableA.flight, tableA.fltno, tableA.stad, Sum(tableA.countValue) AS duplicateCount
FROM tableA
GROUP BY tableA.flight, tableA.fltno, tableA.stad;
```

Then the second query for duplicate rank (ranked by id number) is

```
SELECT (SELECT Count(*)+1 FROM tableA WHERE id < temp.id AND stad = temp.stad AND flight = temp.flight AND fltno = temp.fltno) AS flightRank, temp.id, temp.flight, temp.fltno, temp.stad
FROM tableA AS temp;
```

Then you can join them

```
SELECT tableA.id, tableA.flight, tableA.fltno, tableA.stad, tableA.col1, tableA.col2, queryCounts.duplicateCount, queryRanking.flightRank
FROM (tableA INNER JOIN queryRanking ON tableA.id = queryRanking.id) INNER JOIN queryCounts ON (tableA.stad = queryCounts.stad) AND (tableA.fltno = queryCounts.fltno) AND (tableA.flight = queryCounts.flight);
```

Then regarding the delete query read this thread since you need to delete using joins

[How to delete in MS Access when using JOIN's?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5585732/how-to-delete-in-ms-access-when-using-joins)

Answer (score 0):

This will solve question 1.  I do not believe all 3 questions can be answered in the same query.

```
Select Flight, FltNo, Stad, Sum(1) as DupCnt
from FLT
Group By Flight, FltNo, Stad
order by Sum(1) DESC
```

How do you know you want to delete 8 and 3, and not 4 and 10?