# How to delete rows in one table based on matching ids and date comparison

Tags: sql, ms-access, ms-access-2010

I have two tables: `HIRES1` and `HIRES2` (there is some duplication in names between the lists).

I am trying to delete rows in `HIRES1` when the `PERSONALID is also in`HIRES2`as long as the action date (`actstdt`) in`Hires1`is before the action start date (`actstdt`) in`Hires2`.

**NOTE:** `HIRES1` may have multiple rows for one `personalid` where some dates are before `hires2` dates and some are after `hires2` dates (I want to keep them if after the `hires2` date).

The code that I wrote below asks me to input the parameter value for `hires1.actstdt` and `hires2.actstdt`:

```
DELETE * 
FROM HIRES1 
  WHERE PERSONALID in 
  (
    SELECT DISTINCT PERSONALID 
    FROM HIRES2
  ) AND HIRES1.ACTSTDT < HIRES2.actstdt;
```

Comment: what was your answer?  if it wasn't one of our answers please post what worked for you as an answer and then accept it when it allows you to.

Answer (score 1):

Use [DCount](http://office.microsoft.com/en-us/access-help/dcount-function-HA001228817.aspx) to retrieve the number of `HIRES2` rows which have the same `PERSONALID` and a later `ACTSTDT` as each row in `HIRES1`.  Eventually, you will `DELETE` those `HIRES1` rows for which that count is > 0, but first work out the logic with a `SELECT` query.  Once you have that returning the correct target rows, you can convert it to a `DELETE`.

If I understood the requirements correctly, this should be a reasonable starting point ...

```sql
SELECT *
FROM HIRES1
WHERE
    DCount
        (
            '*',
            'HIRES2',
            'PERSONALID=' & PERSONALID
                & ' AND actstdt>' & Format(ACTSTDT, '\#yyyy-m-d\#')
        ) > 0;
```

I assumed numeric data type for `PERSONALID`.  If it's actually text, you must add quotes around the value in that `DCount` expression.

Comment: that looks complicated. but I haven't ever coded in ms Access SQL

Comment: @Malachi I added a link DCount Function.  Hope that helps.

Comment: Thank you very much.  It was helpful to start with the Select function to confirm it was working correctly.  I then replaced with Delete and it worked perfectly.  Thanks again.

Answer (score 0):

I looked on Google and found another question similar to this one, [Here is the Answer to that Question](https://stackoverflow.com/a/5585773/1214743)

it gives a little bit easier way to do this

```
DELETE HIRES1.*
FROM HIRES1
WHERE EXISTS(SELECT PERSONALID 
             FROM HIRES2 
             WHERE HIRES2.PERSONALID = HIRES1.PERSONALID
                    AND HIRES1.ACTSTDT < HIRES2.actstdt)
```

****This is not tested****

but it should work.

I think your Query didn't work because you had the Date Range part of the query on the outside of the parenthesis.