# How to get delete query to work in MS Access

Tags: sql, ms-access, ms-access-2010

I have set up a subquery to select my records and then the delete query to perform the action. When I run it, I get an error message saying:

> Could not delete from specified tables

Here my SQL code in the delete query:

```
PARAMETERS UnitID Short;
DELETE DISTINCTROW qry_exp_comments_select.*
FROM qry_exp_comments_select;
```

And the called subquery:

```
PARAMETERS UnitID Short;
SELECT tbl_Comments.*, tbl_Activity.ActivityID
FROM tbl_BusUnits INNER JOIN (tbl_Activity INNER JOIN tbl_Comments ON tbl_Activity.ActivityID = tbl_Comments.ActivityID) ON tbl_BusUnits.UnitID = tbl_Activity.UnitID
WHERE (((tbl_BusUnits.UnitID)<>[UnitID]));
```

**Why won't the query work?** I have tried to set it up as the one in the following thread: [MS ACCESS delete query syntax combined with inner join problems](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23228073/ms-access-delete-query-syntax-combined-with-inner-join-problems)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In order to delete all the records in `tbl_Comments` and `tbl_Activity` all I had to do was **change the relationships of the tables so that they have `Cascade Delete` activated.**

Afterwards a simple delete query on the `tbl_BusUnits` also deleted all associated records in the other tables.

Code for the Delete Query as follows:

```
PARAMETERS UnitID Short;
DELETE DISTINCTROW tbl_BusUnits.UnitID
FROM tbl_BusUnits
WHERE (((tbl_BusUnits.UnitID)<>[UnitID]));
```