# How to convert this SELECT Statement into a DELETE statement?

Tags: sql, ms-access, sql-delete

I want to delete all records with a particular id and category except the one with the max date in MS Access.

Edit:
This is how my Data looks like

| id | category | date |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 1 | 24 June 2021 |
| 1 | 1 | 20 June 2021 |
| 1 | 2 | 25 June 2021 |
| 1 | 2 | 26 June 2021 |
| 2 | 1 | 24 June 2021 |
| 2 | 1 | 26 June 2021 |

And this is how i want my data to look like

| id | category | date |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 1 | 24 June 2021 |
| 1 | 2 | 26 June 2021 |
| 2 | 1 | 26 June 2021 |

I have this `SELECT` statement to show me all records I want to keep:

```
Select
    t1.*
From
    table t1
inner join
    (select max(date) as maxdate, id
     from table
     group by id) t2 on t1.id = t2.id 
                     and t1.date = t2.maxdate
```

I can't figure out a `Delete` statement that works in Access.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [MS ACCESS delete query syntax combined with inner join problems](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23228073/ms-access-delete-query-syntax-combined-with-inner-join-problems)

Comment: If i understand you well, you want to remove all records where date is less than max(date). Am i right?

Answer (score 1):

You can use:

```
delete from t
   where t.date < (select max(t2.date)
                   from t as t2
                   where t2.id = t.id and t2.category = t.category
                  );
```