# Delete Records From Left Joined Tables In Access 2007

Tags: sql, ms-access, join, ms-access-2007, sql-delete

So I am trying to delete out part numbers from table E0 that don't match any of the part numbers in table [Part Number] with a left join query using the following SQL statement.

```
DELETE E0.*
FROM E0 LEFT JOIN [Part Number] ON E0.[Part Nbr]=[Part Number].[Part Nbr]
WHERE ((([Part Number].[Part Nbr]) Is Null));
```

When I view what it is selecting, it is correct, but when I try to run the deletion it gives me the error "Could not delete from specified tables"

I'm fairly new to SQL so I'm still a little fuzzy on all the nuances of SQL coding, but from searching on the internet I've found that to delete from joined tables it's different than not joined tables, but following the examples I found what I have should work (but it doesn't).

Comment: Check [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5585732/how-to-delete-in-ms-access-when-using-joins) out.

Comment: I had a feeling it was something simple like that. I guess I was just searching the wrong things... Haha thanks!

Comment: No problem. It's all a learning process. Good luck!