# Why is this Access delete query so slow?

Tags: sql, ms-access

I have a table `featureData` in Access that has ~1.8 million rows.  I have another table `idNumbers` that has ~7000 rows.  I want to delete records from `featureData` using the following query:

```
delete from featuredata where stationId in (select id from previousStationId)
```

This query is very slow (I started running it an hour ago and the progress bar is still less than halfway complete).  Note that `stationId` is an indexed field, but it's slow even when I change its index setting to "No".  Is there way I can speed this up?

Comment: How many rows are you deleting aproximatly?

Comment: Do not use `IN`! Rather then it use `Exists`. Or... use `INNER JOIN`. See: [How to delete in MS Access when using JOIN's?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5585732/how-to-delete-in-ms-access-when-using-joins)

Comment: @MaciejLos `Where Exists` is proceeding at the same rate as `In`.

Comment: Is id also indexed?

Comment: Definitely make sure that `stationId` and `id` are indexed

Comment: Do this with a join rather than an IN. Access may be running "select id from previousStationId" on every record. A join would only do this once. Even at 2M records a delete on an indexed column should happen within minutes.