# SQL: Delete from Table with View as source

Tags: sql, ms-access

I have table like this

```
table1
column1 column2 column3
-----------------------
11      12      13
21      22      23
31      32      33
```

and a View like this

```
view1
column1 column2 column3
-----------------------
11      12      13
31      32      33
```

How to delete rows from table1 that have a match in view1?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/q/5585732/2864740 - perhaps with a WHERE .. EXISTS filter to a subquery. A phrase for this ask is a "delete with join", and it doesn't appear MS Access supports such syntax.

Comment: Or maybe it does .. https://stackoverflow.com/a/889643/2864740 - perhaps relates to MS Access version?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [MS-Access: Selecting rows to delete via joins](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/889517/ms-access-selecting-rows-to-delete-via-joins)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try the below sql query:

```
DELETE Table_1
FROM    Table_1  INNER JOIN  View1 
ON Table_1.col1 = View1.col1  
WHERE   Table_1.col1=View1.col1
```

First join the table and view using `INNER JOIN`, then based on the condition delete the row.