# subselect sql query doesn't work on mysql 4

Tags: mysql, sql

The following sql query works fine on my development server running mysql 5, but when I try it on my live server running mysql 4 it throws an error, can anyone help show me how to adapt my query to run on mysql 4?

```
select * FROM Properties WHERE propertyid IN (select id from todelete)
```

Comment: first run `SELECT id FROM todelete` and see the response

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
SELECT * FROM Properties RIGHT JOIN todelete ON (Properties.propertyid = todelete.id);
```

To delete all rows from Properties which match this condition use this:

```
DELETE Properties FROM Properties INNER JOIN todelete ON (Properties.propertyid = todelete.id);
```

See [T-SQL: Selecting rows to delete via joins](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/439750/t-sql-selecting-rows-to-delete-via-joins)

Comment: Thats great but I want to delete the results of this query from Properties table and I can't do that with the above query

Answer (score 3):

Subqueries are not supported in versions lower than Mysql 4.1.

http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/4.1/en/subqueries.html