# nested select with delete sql statement

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, inner-join

I dunno how do I need to solve it:

i've got a select statement:

```
SELECT 
       sum_lines.id, 
       sum_lines.line_id, 
       sum_lines.summary_id, 
       sum_lines.text_content, 
       sum_tbl.user_id 
FROM 
       sum_lines 
JOIN 
       sum_tbl 
ON 
       sum_lines.summary_id = sum_tbl.id 
WHERE 
       sum_tbl.user_id = 1
```

how can I delete everything that this statement is showing with a delete statement?

Comment: Age-old problem, with an age-old [answer ... http://stackoverflow.com/questions/439750/t-sql-selecting-rows-to-delete-via-joins/439768#439768](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/439750/t-sql-selecting-rows-to-delete-via-joins/439768#439768)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you want to delete from both tables you need two deletes:

```
delete sum_lines
from sum_lines
join sum_tbl on sum_lines.summary_id = sum_tbl.id where sum_tbl.user_id = 1

delete from sum_tbl 
where sum_tbl.user_id = 1
```

Just make sure to do a backup before you delete something. It can easily be done with something like this:

```
select *
into sum_lines_backup
from sum_lines

select *
into sum_tbl_backup
from sum_tbl
```

Comment: My bad, i have updated the answer. You need to specify the table to delete from directly after the "delete" statement.

Answer (score 0):

Try This:

```
delete sum_lines from sum_lines as a

join sum_tbl as b on b.id = a.id 

where b.user_id = 1
```

Make sure the column `name sum_lines[id]` data must match with `sum_tbl[id]`, otherwise it wont work. Maybe `sum_lines.summary_id = sum_tbl.id` is not match data on your database.