# Convert Access delete statement to SQL Server

Tags: sql-server, ms-access, join, sql-delete

I am converting Access to SQL and I got stuck at this Delete Statement because I am not sure what it does exactly.

```
DELETE TableA.cID, TableB.*
FROM TableA RIGHT JOIN TableB ON TableA.cID = TableB.CID2
WHERE (((TableA.cID) Is Null));
```

I am guessing it is something like this:

```
Delete
from TableA right join TableB ON TableA.cID = TableB.CID2
Where TableA.cID is null
```

I am not really sure if it should delete from 1 table or 2 or..

Comment: What you want to do? You want to delete from tableA or table2? please explain more briefly.

Comment: I am trying to figure out what the access query is doing

Answer (score 0):

You want:

```
Delete TableB
from TableA right join TableB ON TableA.cID = TableB.CID2
Where TableA.cID is null
```

Personally, I always avoid right joins because the same thing can be stated by switching the order of the tables.  I would re-write the statement like this:

```
DELETE B
FROM TableB AS B LEFT JOIN TableA AS A ON B.CID2 = A.cID
WHERE A.cID IS NULL
```

See [T-SQL: Selecting rows to delete via joins](https://stackoverflow.com/q/439750/154439) for further information.

---

As for what that query is actually doing, here is a brief description:

> Delete all rows in TableB where no matching record exists in TableA (`TableA.cID IS NULL`) for the condition `TableB.CID2 = TableA.cID`

Comment: But isn't the access query deleting from 2 tables at once?

Comment: No it is not delete from table 2

Comment: No, the `TableA.cID` portion of `DELETE TableA.cID, TableB.*` is likely an artifact of Access's query-by-design view. The original programmer probably double-clicked the `cID` field from TableA to add that field to the query design grid (this is the part that would have added `TableA.cID` to the first line of the query), then typed `Is Null` in the Criteria row of the `TableA.cID` column of the query design grid so that **only rows from TableB with *no* counterpart in TableA** would be deleted by the query. The `TableB.*` in the first line of the query tells Access to only delete from TableB.