# SQL Server query delete results of a join from a table

Tags: sql, sql-server-2005

I'm not a SQL Server expert and I'm struggling with this query. Can anyone help?

```
DELETE
FROM PPTMAILLISTC.dbo.emailTables
WHERE  email IN (SELECT *
FROM PPTMAILLISTC.dbo.emailTables tab1
    INNER JOIN PPTMAILLISTAB.dbo.emailTables tab2
        ON tab1.email = tab2.email)
```

SQL Server Management Studio returns.

> Msg 116, Level 16, State 1, Line 1
>   Only one expression can be specified in the select list when the subquery is not introduced with EXISTS.

Basically, there are 2 separate tables both called the same (`dbo.emailTables`) in 2 separate databases (`PPTMAILLISTC` and `PPTMAILLISTAB`).

Where the both databases have the same results (which I can find out using the join i.e.)

```
SELECT *
FROM PPTMAILLISTC.dbo.emailTables tab1
    INNER JOIN PPTMAILLISTAB.dbo.emailTables tab2
        ON tab1.email = tab2.email
```

I want to delete the results of this join from `PPTMAILLISTC.dbo.emailTables`.

Answer (score 1):

You can get rid of the use of IN and just use your inner SELECT statement and convert it to a DELETE and just reference the ALIAS (tab1) of the table you actually want to affect like this:

```
DELETE  tab1
FROM    PPTMAILLISTC.dbo.emailTables tab1
        INNER JOIN PPTMAILLISTAB.dbo.emailTables tab2 ON tab1.email = tab2.email
```

Comment: Here's another good example of this: [t-sql-selecting-rows-to-delete-via-joins](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/439750/t-sql-selecting-rows-to-delete-via-joins)

Comment: Hi db_brad! Thanks so much. Worked like a charm. This was really really good of you to take the time to help. Thanks so much!!!

Comment: No problem Dave! Happy to help.

Answer (score 0):

You need something like this:

```
DELETE FROM PPTMAILLISTC.dbo.emailTables
    WHERE email IN (SELECT tab1.email
                    FROM PPTMAILLISTC.dbo.emailTables tab1 INNER JOIN
                         PPTMAILLISTAB.dbo.emailTables tab2
                         ON tab1.email = tab2.email
                   );
```

Even if both tables have only one column, the `*` resolves to two columns `tab1.email` and `tab2.email`.  As the error message says, the `select` list for an `in` subquery can have only one column.

EDIT:

This is actually simpler to write as:

```
DELETE FROM PPTMAILLISTC.dbo.emailTables
    WHERE email IN (SELECT tab2.email
                    FROM PPTMAILLISTAB.dbo.emailTables tab2
                   );
```

You don't need to do the join in the `in` subquery.